# Как сделать комбинированную покупку iap

Tags: unity3d

прошу помощи. Столкнулся с проблемой. При создании покупок необходимо сделать пак для покупки (отключение рекламы + расходники) и данный товар можно покупать неограниченное количество раз. Как мне известно после переустановки игры можно восстановить только нерасходуемые покупки, но в данном случае надо лишь восстановить только рекламу, как это можно сделать. Пробовал обыграть ситуацию через прикрепление 2 компонентов IAP button к 1 кнопке (как через саму кнопку, так и через разные gameObject) и при нажатии по кнопке методы срабатывали сразу, независимо, куплен товар или нет